# Is it possible to give user choice to use their own firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making one Android app where I am using Firebase Realtime Database. However, I want user to give choice to either use my firebase database or **their own**. Is this even possible? Is there way to configure android app such that user can use their own Firebase-Database? Maybe by using their own API keys/project-url or something?

I am looking for implementation like Google-Drive API, where one can store content to users own Google Drive.

Currently, I can think of only one possible way to achieve this : user compiling their own app with their own `google.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to get them to provide all the data that would be passed to a call to [initializeApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp#initializeApp(android.content.Context,%20com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions,%20java.lang.String)) via [FirebaseOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions), then use the returned FirebaseApp instance for all database access.

They would also have to configure Firebase Authentication and security ruels so they don't have a publicly readable and writable database instance, and your app would have to manage the user sign-in.

This is all going to be a non-trivial amount of work for both you and the user, if you choose to implement it.